# how to change height specific div when scroll inside this div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help in JS :
I have page with div class .maincom inside with overlay-y: scroll. I want to scroll this div, and when scrolling I want to change height of div class .maincom from 160 to 350 .

Important: I don't want to change height of this div when I'm scrolling entire site (window). I want to change this height ONLY when I'm scrolling this div class .maincom  .

Example code:

```
<div class="maincom">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active">
<a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li></ul>
<h2>Your comment</h2>
<form>...</form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.maincom {
position: fixed;
background-color: white;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
height: 160px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
display: block;
clear: both;
background: white;
margin-bottom: 0px;
z-index: 4;
}
```

Div "maincom" is overlay-y:scroll, with height: 160px . I'm searching for solution: when maincom is scrolled down, then height will be 350px . When scrolled up, height will be back as 160px

This isn't working correctly :

```
$(".maincom").on("scroll", function () {
        var scrollTop = $(".maincom").scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > 100) {
            $(".maincom").stop().animate({height: "160px"},200);
        }
        else {
             $(".maincom").stop().animate({height: "350px"},200);   
        }
     });
```

Any other solutions? :)

First step is completed now. here is the second/last one:

Update: Solution from Lime In The Coconut working fully great. Thanks a lot ! Now I have one more thing:

Example code 2:

```
<div class="reward">You can win 50 points for that</div>
    <div class="maincom">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
        <a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li></ul>
        <h2>Your comment</h2>
        <form>...</form>
        </div>
```

and code for .reward class div:

```
.reward{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 140px;
    right: -20px;
    height: 64px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    background: white;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #0077dd;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

And now: how to set JS - if .maincom is scrolled down (then height of .maincom increased) , bottom of .reward is increased from 140px to 300px .

if You know solution for that too, You are the best ! :)

Thanks !
Peter

Comment: Post your code as a minimal snippet so someone can help you.

Comment: added - sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, i have inserted more list elements in order to see the effects

```js
let maincom = document.querySelector('.maincom')

maincom.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
 if(this.scrollTop>0){
   this.style.height ="360px"
  }
  if(this.scrollTop === 0){
   this.style.height = '160px'
  }

})
```

```css
.maincom {
position: fixed;
background-color: red;
width: 100%;

height: 160px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
display: block;
clear: both;
background: white;
margin-bottom: 0px;
z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="maincom">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active">
<a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
<li class="active">
<a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
<li class="active">
<a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
<li class="active">
<a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
<li class="active">
<a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
<li class="active">
<a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
<li class="active">
<a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
<li class="active">
<a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
<li class="active">
<a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
<li class="active">
<a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
<li class="active">
<a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
<li class="active">
<a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
<li class="active">
<a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
<li class="active">
<a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
<li class="active">
<a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
<li class="active">
<a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
<li class="active">
<a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
<li class="active">
<a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
</ul>
<h2>Your comment</h2>
<form>...</form>
</div>
```

Comment: You are the best - it's working ! Now can You check update for my post, please? :) It's the last step to do :)

Comment: voted, but I'm new on this site and my vote isn't visible. But marked as solved, so I hope this will help You / increase reputation :)

I will be here usually, so I will give You vote up after I received that 15 points + (i hope for that) :)

Comment: thanks :), maybe post a snippet with all the code involved, as i do in my answer and i try to figured out whats going on, maybe not now because is late here

Comment: yeah - i was updated my post (from example code 2) , so this will be helpful I hope :) thanks !

Comment: No i mean to post your actual code in a snippet runnable https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/